# Property of villainous matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

---

Say that an $N \times N$ binary matrix $M \in \mathrm{Mat}_{N \times N}(\{0,1\})$ is *villainous* if it does not contain the submatrix $I_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1& 0\\
 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$.

Show that for any constant $\kappa < 1/80$, every villainous $N\times N$ matrix contains a submatrix of size at least $\kappa N\times \kappa N$ such that all of the elements of the submatrix are equal.

---

I've tried to think about the problem and had a few thoughts. For example, a villainous matrix may contain the submatrix $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, and so there's some level of 'invariance' here: the transpose of a villainous matrix is not necessarily villainous, so maybe a symmetry argument will not be helpful here.

Next I tried to define precisely what a submatrix is, because the book doesn't mention it at all. It cannot refer to a contiguous block, since the statement wouldn't be true then: if we take a $N \times N$ matrix with $1$'s on the diagonals directed north-east to south-west and spaced 3 positions apart with all other elements be zeroes, it does not contain $I_2$ as contiguous block and it does not contain (contiguous) $3 \times 3$ submatrix with equal elements. So, by $N \times N$ "submatrix", I'm pretty sure we're referring to the intersection of any $N$ rows and $N$ columns.

The problem though is that I'm not sure how I might attack the problem. The book is for a first course in linear algebra and only marks it as a medium difficulty problem, so I don't believe we'll absolutely need to resort to any deep theorems in linear algebra to make real progress on the problem. Any help will be great!

Comment: Is there such a book? I cannot find it on Amazon or Google. Any link to the publisher?

Comment: I only have a physical copy which was given to me as a gift. I believe it's published by Evans Brothers.

Comment: You didn't introduce $n$, and you never used the "positive constant". Perhaps $n$ is missing after "a positive constant"?

Comment: Ah sorry; I have fixed the issues.

Comment: 'Villainous' to describe a lack of non-trivial identity is dramatic, but I don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The high-level, *highly informal* motivation for the solution below is the following: to determine whether a given matrix $M$ is villainous, it suffices to "recurse" within the size of the matrix up to some sufficient "depth" for which we can check whether $I_2$ is "contained within" $M$. This will be in some sense the guiding principle for our entire solution to this problem.

More precisely, consider the following fact, which is paraphrased from Nicholas J. Harvey's paper [*Algebraic Algorithms from Matching and Matroid Problems*](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/070684008) [Har09] and should be in at least one other linear algebra text:

**Fact** (Corollary 2.2 in [Har09])**.** Let $M$ be a nonsingular matrix and let $N = M^{-1}$. Let $\tilde{M}$ be a matrix that is entirely identical to $M$ except that $\tilde{M}_{S, S} \neq M_{S, S}$ for some subset $S$ of the rows and columns of $M$. Furthermore, let $\Delta = \tilde{M} - M$. Then:

- $\tilde{M}$ is nonsingular if and only if $\det(I + N_{S, S}\Delta_{S,S}) \neq 0$.
- If $\tilde{M}$ is nonsingular, then
  $$\tilde{M}^{-1} = N - N_{*,S} (I+N_{S,S}\Delta_{S,S})^{-1}\Delta_{S,S}N_{S,*}.$$
- Restricting $\tilde{M}^{-1}$ to a subset $T$, we have that $$\tilde{M}^{-1}_{T, T} = N_{T, T} - N_{T, S}(I + N_{S, S}\Delta_{S, S})^{-1}\Delta_{S, S}N_{S, T}.$$

*Proof.* See Appendix A.1 of [Har09]. The proof is exactly the same but with some minor differences that are instructive for us. $\square$

The following straightforward fact is a bit more obvious when you see the proof of the fact above. It should also be in some linear algebra textbooks (although probably left as an exercise).

**Fact.** Let $m_{ij}$ be an entry of $M$ with $m_{ij} = 0$ such that there exist $i_k, j_k$ with $k \in [p]$ satisfying the following conditions: for $i_k \in [1, i)$ and $j_k \in (j, N]$, it holds that $m_{i_k, j} = m_{i, j_k} = 1$ for all $k \in [p]$. If $M$ does not contain an $p \times p$ submatrix with all entries equalling $1$, then $M$ contains $I_2$ as a submatrix, and therefore is not villainous.
*Proof sketch.* By exemplar, take $\begin{pmatrix}
m_{i_k,j} & m_{i_k,j_\ell}\\
m_{i,j} & m_{i,j_\ell}
\end{pmatrix}$. Since $M$ does not contain $I_2$ it implies $m_{i_k,j_\ell}=1$ for $1\leq k,\ell\leq p$. So $M$ contains a $p\times p$ submatrix with all entries being $1$'s. $\square$

The "recursive mentality" we have built up to this point will now come useful for us. Delineate the $N \times N$ matrix $M$ into four other block matrices bounded within, for $p = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$, (1) the horizontal line passing through the $p$-th and $(p+1)$-th rows, and (2) the vertical line passing through the $p$-th and $(p+1)$-th columns. Call these matrices $M_1, M_2, M_3, M_4$:

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} M_1 & M_2\\ M_3 & M_4\end{pmatrix}.$$

The following facts will be crucial for our eventual proof:

**Fact.** Let $\kappa>0$ and $M$ be $N\times N$ matrix, each element either $1$ or $0$. If $M$ does not contain $I_2$ as a submatrix and $M$ does not contain a submatrix of size greater than $\kappa N \times \kappa N$ and with equal elements, then one of the matrices $M_1, M_4$ has at most $8\kappa (p+1)^2$ elements equal to $1$, where $p = \left \lfloor {N}/{2}\right \rfloor$.
*Proof.* Let $j_1,j_2,\dots,j_\ell$ be those columns of $M_1$ containing at least $\kappa N$ $1$'s and $i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k$ be those rows of $M_4$ each one with at least $\kappa N$ $1$'s. Suppose both $k,\ell$ are (much) greater than $\kappa N$. Then one of the following possibilities actually holds:

1. All the $m_{i_s,p+j_r}$ are equal to $1$ in which case there exists $\kappa N\times \kappa N$ submatrix by the second fact above, which is clearly impossible.
2. Some $m_{i_s,p+j_r}=0$, in which case by the second fact above there is again a $\kappa N \times \kappa N$ submatrix; impossible.
   Thus, either $k$ or $\ell$ is at most $\kappa N$. It is not $\ell$, as we are recursing along the major diagonal, so $k \leq \kappa N$. Then via a basic counting argument we know the number of $1$'s in $M_1$ is at most $2\kappa N^2\leq 8\kappa(p+1)^2$, which proves the fact. $\square$

**Fact.** Let $\kappa>0$ and $M$ be $N\times N$ matrix, each element either $1$ or $0$. If $M$ does not contain $I_2$ as a submatrix and $M$ does not contain a submatrix of size greater than $\kappa N \times \kappa N$ and with equal elements, then one of the matrices $M_2, M_4$ has at most $8\kappa (p+1)^2$ elements equal to $0$, where $p = \left \lfloor {n}/{2}\right \rfloor$.
*Proof.* Just as above; you can easily sketch it yourself. $\square$

---

The above is merely the setup. We'll turn our attention to proving the claim of the problem. Suppose towards contradiction that it is not true. By the third fact above it immediately follows that one of submatrices $M_1, M_4$ (not this one for the same reason as before), that is, $M_1$, has at most $8\kappa (p+1)^2$ elements equal to $1$, where $p$ is its size. Now apply the last fact above to $M_1$ to get that there are at most $8\kappa(p_1+1)^2$ zeroes in one of the recursed matrices $(M_4)_4, (M_2)_2$. It follows then that the number of $1$'s in $M_1$ is at least $$p_1^2-8\kappa(p_1+1)^2\geq \frac{p^2}{4}-8\kappa\left(\frac{p}{2}+2\right)^2=\frac{p^2}{4}-2\kappa(p+4)^2,$$ where $p_1=\lfloor{p}/{2}\rfloor$. Thus if the number of $1$'s in $M_1$ is $O_1$, we get:

$$\frac{p^2}{4}-2\kappa(p+4)^2 \leq O_1 \leq 8\kappa(p+1)^2,$$and hence
$p^2\leq 40\kappa(p+4)^2,$for all $p > 0$. But this is impossible since $\kappa < {1}/{80}$ (otherwise, we would have $2p^2 < p^2 + 8p + 16 \implies p^2 - 8p - 16 < 0$ for all $p$, which is obviously false). Therefore a contradiction is established, and the claim of the problem is indeed true.

Comment: Wow, that's very... detailed. Can you explain where there's the recursion here?

Comment: Yes - essentially we are starting at a root (which you can think of as the smallest subsub... matrix for which $M_1, \ldots, M_4$ are all real numbers), and circling around, examining all the other numbers as we move above levels. This is why we refer to $(M_2)_{\cdots 2}$, etc.